# IOS: stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString don't work

Tags: ios, xcode, string

filepath:/var/mobile/Applications/BA7AE6F8-C7EA-4601-A5F4-30E3C57FE948/Documents/photo2.jpg
photonumber:/var/mobile/Applications/BA7AE6F8-C7EA-4601-A5F4-30E3C57FE948/Documents/2

index = 2;

```
NSString *nextSequentialFile =
            [filePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:photoNumber
                                                withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", index+1]
                                                   options:NSBackwardsSearch
                                                     range:NSMakeRange(0, filePath.length)];
```

the result is ever 
nextsequenzial:/var/mobile/Applications/BA7AE6F8-C7EA-4601-A5F4-30E3C57FE948/Documents/photo2.jpg

why?

it must be /photo3.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filepath` doesn't contain `photonumber`, so there's nothing to replace.  Note that `photonumber` ends with `/Documents/2` while `filepath` contains `/Documents/photo2.jpg`.

`photonumber` needs to be changed to end in `/Documents/photo2` and the replacement string needs to be changed to `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/photo%d", index+1]`.